# Help understanding the Binomial Distribution for nonindependent events?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Apologies if this seems like a basic question, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer in my textbook or online.

The original problem;

Please determine the probability of finding exactly 3 defective and 7 non-defective items if we pick 10 items from a lot consisting of 20 defective and 80 non-defective (without replacement).

From what I've managed to find, the probability for a binomial distribution would've been $nPk*(p^k)*(1-p)^{n-k}$, but this seems to only apply in cases where there is a consistent probability across trials.

I tried $100P10 * (\frac{20}{100})(\frac{19}{99})(\frac{18}{98})(\frac{80}{97})(\frac{79}{96})...(\frac{73}{90})$ but I got a number in the tens of billions instead of anything that could reasonably be a probability.

Any advice on how I should change the binomial distribution to make it function with the problem?

Comment: For sampling without replacement like this, instead of the binomial distribution, you want to be using the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Oh my soul, I feel silly now. Thank you so much! For some reason our textbook only has binomial, geometric and poisson distributions.

Comment: You're welcome!